# How to write header row with csv.DictWriter?

Tags: python, csv

Assume I have a `csv.DictReader` object and I want to write it out as a CSV file. How can I do this?

I know that I can write the **rows of data** like this:

```
dr = csv.DictReader(open(f), delimiter='\t')
# process my dr object
# ...
# write out object
output = csv.DictWriter(open(f2, 'w'), delimiter='\t')
for item in dr:
    output.writerow(item)
```

But how can I include the fieldnames?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Edit:
In 2.7 / 3.2 there is [a new `writeheader()` method](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader). Also, John Machin's answer provides a simpler method of writing the header row.
Simple example of using the `writeheader()` method now available in 2.7 / 3.2:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_fieldnames = OrderedDict([('field1',None),('field2',None)])
with open(outfile,'wb') as fou:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=ordered_fieldnames)
    dw.writeheader()
    # continue on to write data
```

---

Instantiating DictWriter requires a fieldnames argument.
From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

> The fieldnames parameter identifies
>   the order in which values in the
>   dictionary passed to the writerow()
>   method are written to the csvfile.

Put another way:  The Fieldnames argument is required because Python dicts are inherently unordered.
Below is an example of how you'd write the header and data to a file.
Note: `with` statement was added in 2.6. If using 2.5: `from __future__ import with_statement`

```
with open(infile,'rb') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter='\t')

# dr.fieldnames contains values from first row of `f`.
with open(outfile,'wb') as fou:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=dr.fieldnames)
    headers = {} 
    for n in dw.fieldnames:
        headers[n] = n
    dw.writerow(headers)
    for row in dr:
        dw.writerow(row)
```

As @FM mentions in a comment, you can condense header-writing to a one-liner, e.g.:

```
with open(outfile,'wb') as fou:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=dr.fieldnames)
    dw.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in dr.fieldnames))
    for row in dr:
        dw.writerow(row)
```

Comment: +1 Yet another way to write the header: `dw.writerow( dict((f,f) for f in dr.fieldnames) )`.

Comment: @Adam: for a shorter one-liner, see my answer.

Comment: @John: +1 to your answer; simply utilising "the underlying writer instance" is certainly preferable to "laborious identity-mapping".

Comment: Can you make the new method more prominent?  I read your answer but didn't notice it.

Comment: @endolith: thanks for the feedback. Moved that portion to top of answer.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why cant you just do dw.writeheader()

Comment: Since you're using a dictReader as well, then it is easy to add the fields with `dw = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=dr.fieldnames)`. That way, if your fields change you do not need to adjust the dictWriter.

Comment: Oh and don't forget the *very important* `restval` and `extrasaction` [from the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). Nasty, brittle hacks are necessary if you don't use those.

Comment: Using an `OrderedDict` to be able to pass an ordered sequence of fieldnames to `csv.DictWriter` seems totally unwarranted, since a `tuple` or `list` would work equally well. i.e. `ordered_fieldnames = 'field1', 'field2'`.

Answer (score 31):

A few options:

(1) Laboriously make an identity-mapping (i.e. do-nothing) dict out of your fieldnames so that csv.DictWriter can convert it back to a list and pass it to a csv.writer instance.

(2) The documentation mentions "the underlying `writer` instance" ... so just use it (example at the end).

```
dw.writer.writerow(dw.fieldnames)
```

(3) Avoid the csv.Dictwriter overhead and do it yourself with csv.writer

Writing data:

```
w.writerow([d[k] for k in fieldnames])
```

or

```
w.writerow([d.get(k, restval) for k in fieldnames])
```

Instead of the `extrasaction` "functionality", I'd prefer to code it myself; that way you can report ALL "extras" with the keys and values, not just the first extra key. What is a real nuisance with DictWriter is that if you've verified the keys yourself as each dict was being built, you need to remember to use extrasaction='ignore' otherwise it's going to SLOWLY (fieldnames is a list) repeat the check:

```
wrong_fields = [k for k in rowdict if k not in self.fieldnames]
```

============

```
>>> f = open('csvtest.csv', 'wb')
>>> import csv
>>> fns = 'foo bar zot'.split()
>>> dw = csv.DictWriter(f, fns, restval='Huh?')
# dw.writefieldnames(fns) -- no such animal
>>> dw.writerow(fns) # no such luck, it can't imagine what to do with a list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python26\lib\csv.py", line 144, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\python26\lib\csv.py", line 141, in _dict_to_list
    return [rowdict.get(key, self.restval) for key in self.fieldnames]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
>>> dir(dw)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', '_dict_to_list', 'extrasaction', 'fieldnam
es', 'restval', 'writer', 'writerow', 'writerows']
# eureka
>>> dw.writer.writerow(dw.fieldnames)
>>> dw.writerow({'foo':'oof'})
>>> f.close()
>>> open('csvtest.csv', 'rb').read()
'foo,bar,zot\r\noof,Huh?,Huh?\r\n'
>>>
```

Comment: Currently in Python 3.6, the `extrasaction` functionality seems to implemented better. It's now `wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames so it's effectively a `set` operation.

Comment: I'm voting this answer up for the 'avoid DictWriter' comment - I haven't seen any advantage to using it, and seems quicker to structure your data and use csv.writer

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do this would be to add before adding lines in your output, the following line :

```
output.writerow(dict(zip(dr.fieldnames, dr.fieldnames)))
```

The zip would return a list of doublet containing the same value. This list could be used to initiate a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

```
writer.writeheader()
```

Above works like charm. Just don't forget to add your `fieldnames` attribute when intializing your `csv.DictWriter`