# How do I convert this list of dictionaries to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, data-conversion

I have a list of dictionaries that looks something like this:

```
toCSV = [{'name':'bob','age':25,'weight':200},{'name':'jim','age':31,'weight':180}]
```

What should I do to convert this to a csv file that looks something like this:

```
name,age,weight
bob,25,200
jim,31,180
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing header in csv python with DictWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982023/writing-header-in-csv-python-with-dictwriter)

Answer (score 474, accepted):

```py
import csv

to_csv = [
    {'name': 'bob', 'age': 25, 'weight': 200},
    {'name': 'jim', 'age': 31, 'weight': 180},
]

keys = to_csv[0].keys()

with open('people.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(to_csv)
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this when the data is embedded? for example if it is {{"first":"John", "last": "Doe"}, uri} for each entry in the array but you want the csv to contain only data for first and last?

Comment: How can I write file like this to CSV format if I have Cyrillic symbols in dictionary's values? I tried  .encode('utf-8') but unfortunately in CSV file values do not shows correctly.

Comment: this program write output in reverse order like weightage name weight
25 bob 200
31 jim 180

Comment: Does not work if first list item does not contain all keys

Comment: `set().union(*(d.keys() for d in mylist))` to get all the keys in the list (if you have some which don't have all the keys.)

Comment: The data does not seem to split into columns for me using this answer, but instead is written into in a single column seperated by comma. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: @Astarno Yes, this is normal. A CSV file is just a text file. You are probably using a "table calculation tool" to view your CSV. You have to import the data from the CSV (while specifying a delimiter character and a quoting character) into your software/tool to be able to view different columns.

Answer (score 39):

In python 3 things are a little different, but way simpler and less error prone. It's a good idea to tell the CSV your file should be opened with `utf8` encoding, as it makes that data more portable to others (assuming you aren't using a more restrictive encoding, like `latin1`)

```
import csv
toCSV = [{'name':'bob','age':25,'weight':200},
         {'name':'jim','age':31,'weight':180}]
with open('people.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as output_file:
    fc = csv.DictWriter(output_file, 
                        fieldnames=toCSV[0].keys(),

                       )
    fc.writeheader()
    fc.writerows(toCSV)
```

- Note that `csv` in python 3 needs the `newline=''` parameter, otherwise you get blank lines in your CSV when opening in excel/opencalc.

Alternatively: I prefer use to the csv handler in the `pandas` module. I find it is more tolerant of encoding issues, and **pandas will automatically convert string numbers in CSVs into the correct type (int,float,etc) when loading the file.**

```
import pandas
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(filepath)
list_of_dictionaries = dataframe.to_dict('records')
dataframe.to_csv(filepath)
```

Note:

- pandas will take care of opening the file for you if you give it a path, and will default to `utf8` in python3, and figure out headers too.
- a dataframe is not the same structure as what CSV gives you, so you add one line upon loading to get the same thing: `dataframe.to_dict('records')`
- pandas also makes it much easier to control the order of columns in your csv file. By default, they're alphabetical, but you can specify the column order. With vanilla `csv` module, you need to feed it an `OrderedDict` or they'll appear in a random order (if working in python < 3.5). See: [Preserving column order in Python Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653688/preserving-column-order-in-python-pandas-dataframe) for more.

Comment: How is list_of_dictionaries written to CSV? I can't make sense of the second code example.

Comment: @IainSamuelMcLeanElder `.to_dict` returns your dataframe in one of several formats, depending what you specify. ('records') returns a list of dictionaries where each column is a dictionary, and `.to_dict('index')` returns a dictionary of dictionaries, with top-level keys being the index values, and the nested dictionary being `column:value` pairs. Depending on how you export your csv, you choose the structure the CSV function expects.

Comment: Your second code example doesn't seem to answer the OP's question. Shouldn't it be using `from_dict` somwhere? I had the same problem and that's what worked for me. That's good to know about to_dict, but it seems more relevant for reading, not writing.

Answer (score 19):

this is when you have one dictionary list:

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
```

Answer (score 11):

a short solution with Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_dicts = [
    {'name': 'bob', 'age': 25, 'weight': 200},
    {'name': 'jim', 'age': 31, 'weight': 180},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts) 
df.to_csv("names.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 9):

Because @User and @BiXiC asked for help with UTF-8 here a variation of the solution by @Matthew. (I'm not allowed to comment, so I'm answering.)

```
import unicodecsv as csv
toCSV = [{'name':'bob','age':25,'weight':200},
         {'name':'jim','age':31,'weight':180}]
keys = toCSV[0].keys()
with open('people.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(toCSV)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another, more general solution assuming you don't have a list of rows (maybe they don't fit in memory) or a copy of the headers (maybe the `write_csv` function is generic):

```
def gen_rows():
    yield OrderedDict(name='bob', age=25, weight=200)
    yield OrderedDict(name='jim', age=31, weight=180)

def write_csv():
    it = genrows()
    first_row = it.next()  # __next__ in py3
    with open("people.csv", "w") as outfile:
        wr = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=list(first_row))
        wr.writeheader()
        wr.writerow(first_row)
        wr.writerows(it)
```

*Note*: the OrderedDict constructor used here only preserves order in python >3.4. If order is important, use the `OrderedDict([('name', 'bob'),('age',25)])` form.

Comment: never saw anyone store data in a generator before - interesting approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

with open('file_name.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(('colum1', 'colum2', 'colum3'))
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value[0], value[1]])
```

This would be the simplest way to write data to **.csv** file

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
toCSV = [{'name':'bob','age':25,'weight':200},
         {'name':'jim','age':31,'weight':180}]
header=['name','age','weight']     
try:
   with open('output'+str(date.today())+'.csv',mode='w',encoding='utf8',newline='') as output_to_csv:
       dict_csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_to_csv, fieldnames=header,dialect='excel')
       dict_csv_writer.writeheader()
       dict_csv_writer.writerows(toCSV)
   print('\nData exported to csv succesfully and sample data')
except IOError as io:
    print('\n',io)
```