# Preserving column order in the pandas to_csv method

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

The to_csv method of pandas does not preserve the order of columns. It chooses to alphabetically arrange the columns in CSV. This is a bug and has been reported and is supposed to be corrected in version 0.11.0. I have 0.18.0.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'V_pod_error' : [a],
                   'V_pod_used' : [b],
                   'U_sol_type' : [c]
                                ...
                                ... and so on upto 50 columns }

pd.to_csv(df)
```

Excel order:

```
0   U_sol type          V_pod_error      V_pod_used      ...
1
```

What I want is order in the dictionary:

```
0   V_pod_error      V_pod_used          U_sol type     ...
1
```

I have a huge number of columns and names. I cannot do it manually or write out the column order. There has been the exact same question in 2013 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653688/preserving-column-order-in-python-pandas-dataframe). And it doesnt look like there is an update! I would like to ask the community to help me out! This is really problematic.

Comment: Yes, I am constructing the data frame in a loop with the above commands. Will check out ordered dict. Thanks.  The thing is I kept updating in a quick and dirty manner as and when I needed things. Now to work with it is really hard. In order to add a column to the end I prefix the column name with 'z'(quick and dirty). Any other suggestions of simple manipulations to my existing code to get the desired as defined output?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try the following solution. Even I faced the same issue. I solved it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'V_pod_error' : [a],
                   'V_pod_used' : [b],
                   'U_sol_type' : [c]
                                ...
                                ... and so on upto 50 columns }

column_order = ['V_pod_error', 'V_pod_used', 'U_sol_type',.....# upto 50 column names]

df[column_order].to_csv(file_name)
```

Answer (score 9):

I think problem is in `DataFrame` constructor, because you need add parameter `columns` for custom ordering of columns. If you dont set parameter columns, columns are ordered alphanumerical.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'V_pod_error' : [0,2],
                   'V_pod_used' : [6,4],
                   'U_sol_type' : [7,8]})
print df
   U_sol_type  V_pod_error  V_pod_used
0           7            0           6
1           8            2           4

print df.to_csv()
,U_sol_type,V_pod_error,V_pod_used
0,7,0,6
1,8,2,4


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'V_pod_error' : [0,2],
                   'V_pod_used' : [6,4],
                   'U_sol_type' : [7,8]}, 
                    columns=['V_pod_error','V_pod_used','U_sol_type'])

print df1
   V_pod_error  V_pod_used  U_sol_type
0            0           6           7
1            2           4           8

print df1.to_csv()
,V_pod_error,V_pod_used,U_sol_type
0,0,6,7
1,2,4,8
```

EDIT:

Another solution is set order of column by subset before write [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) (thanks [Mathias711](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070759/preserving-column-order-in-the-pandas-to-csv-method#comment61686687_37070820)):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'V_pod_error' : [0,2],
                   'V_pod_used' : [6,4],
                   'U_sol_type' : [7,8]})
print df
   U_sol_type  V_pod_error  V_pod_used
0           7            0           6
1           8            2           4

df = df[['V_pod_error','V_pod_used','U_sol_type']]
print df

   V_pod_error  V_pod_used  U_sol_type
0            0           6           7
1            2           4           8
```

EDIT1: Maybe help first convert `dict` to `OrderedDict` and then create `DataFrame`:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd


d = {'V_pod_error' : [0,2],'V_pod_used' : [6,4], 'U_sol_type' : [7,8]}
print d
{'V_pod_error': [0, 2], 'V_pod_used': [6, 4], 'U_sol_type': [7, 8]}

print pd.DataFrame(d)
   U_sol_type  V_pod_error  V_pod_used
0           7            0           6
1           8            2           4

d1 = collections.OrderedDict(d)
print d1
OrderedDict([('V_pod_error', [0, 2]), ('V_pod_used', [6, 4]), ('U_sol_type', [7, 8])])

print pd.DataFrame(d1)
   V_pod_error  V_pod_used  U_sol_type
0            0           6           7
1            2           4           8
```

Comment: Can it also help to call `df = df[[columns]]` right before `df.to_csv()`? Normally this will change the order of your columns

Comment: Yes, this is another option. Thanks. I add it to answer.

Comment: @jexrael Thanks for your immediate response. But, I am not sure we are on the same page. I understand that we need to do it manually. But I dont want to do it manually by writing out the column structure as I have too many columns. I want the dataframe column structure to be preserved. I want what is in the data frame to show up in the csv without any fuss.

Comment: @Mathias711 Are you saying that if I do df = "df[[columns]]" (the exact same words as you have written), then it should work? I am just wondering if "df = df[[columns]]" means df[[col1,col2,col3]].

Comment: @ThejKiran - But I think it is other problem - how you can change sort of columns to custom? Because if creates dataframe without parameter columns, they are alphanumeric sorted. And what is rule for custum sorting? I think help only Mathias solution, see edit in my answer. Btw, for creating DataFrame is used Dictionary, so sorting in default dictionary is impossible.

Comment: @jexrael the most important take away from this is that the problem is wit the df and not to_csv. STUD point! Should I edit the question to match your point?

Comment: @ThejKiran What is order in `print df.columns` ? I think it is `Excel` order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111223/discussion-between-thej-kiran-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', header=True, columns=["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"])
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html