# compare values with fieldnames before writing it in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, field-names

I'm using this code to compare value with their affiliated fieldnames before i store it in the csv-file to check the right column, because everytime when i reboot my machine the order of sensors in the dictionary will be changed autamatically. this why i have to control the the position of value in dict before i store it in csv file, otherwise i will get a mess csv file like the example bellow which provide the value temperatur is 1000 [°C] the luminisity 10 [lux]

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time
from collections import OrderedDict
from time import sleep


Datum = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
Time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()

data = {'Stecker Energy': '2.37', 'Stromzaehler Strom L1 [A]': '0.0', '1OG Ultraviolet': '0.0','Stecker EG  Energie [kWh]': '4.3'}

filename = Datum + 'SOF.csv'
if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    outfile = open(filename, "w")
    lineKey = ""
    for x in data.keys():
        lineKey+= x + ","
    lineKey = 'Time '+ "," + lineKey[:-1]+"\n" # Delete last character and add new line
    outfile = open(filename, "a")
    outfile.write(lineKey)
    outfile.close()

#check first line of  fieldnames 
with open(filename,'r') as myFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(myFile)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
    myFile.close()
#Compare the values with their  keys (fieldnames)
with open(filename,'a') as outfile:
    lineValue = ""
    for sensor, value  in data.items():
        if sensor in data.items()==sensor in fieldnames:
            v = data[sensor]
            print("v", v)
            lineValue+= str(v) + "," 
    lineValue = Time + "," + lineValue[:-1] + "\n"
    print(lineValue)
    outfile.write(lineValue)
    outfile.close()
```

The problem is when i check CSV-file i found that value are written in the wrong column which means wrong fieldnames for Examlpe:

**Example of this problem in CSV file**

[image: Example of this problem in csv file]

CSV Text Example

Time ,Stromzaehler Strom L1 [A],Stecker Energy,1OG Ultraviolet,Stecker EG  Energie [kWh]
2017-11-21T17:56:10,2.37,0.0,0.0,4.3
2017-11-21T17:56:26,4.3,0.0,0.0,2.37
2017-11-21T17:56:28,0,0.0,2.37,4.3
2017-11-21T17:56:30,0,2.37,0.0,4.3

```
data = {'Stecker Energy': '', 'Stromzaehler Strom L1 [A]': '', '1OG Ultraviolet': '','Stecker EG  Energie [kWh]': ''}
```

Comment: Please post a textual version of your CSV file rather than an image.

Comment: @MartinEvans i edited my post. you can find i a textual version example above

Comment: What are the contents of the `data` object?

Comment: Perhaps instead of manually constructing the output data by adding commas and newlines and such, you could use the `csv.DictWriter` class. This vastly reduces the likelihood of misplacing a separator character, and also gives your code a nice symmetrical feel since it's already using `DictReader` in the first half.

Comment: When I run your code, `print(fieldnames)` shows `['Time    Temp  Humidity  Current  ']` which looks wrong. The list should be four items long, not one. If your input file doesn't contain any commas, then I think you need to configure the DictReader so that it is aware of that fact.

Comment: @Kevin i have comma in my text file. i edited and i post it here

Comment: why not pandas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070759/preserving-column-order-in-the-pandas-to-csv-method is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for sensor, value  in data.items():
    if sensor in data.items()==sensor in fieldnames:
        v = data[sensor]
        print("v", v)
        lineValue+= str(v) + ","
```

This doesn't look right to me. If you just want to iterate through all the fieldnames (other than "Time") and add the values in `data` that correspond to those fields, while also putting "n/a" for values not present in `data`, then I suggest doing:

```
with open(filename,'a') as outfile:
    lineValue = ""
    for fieldname in fieldnames[1:]: #skip the first one, since that's Time, which we have a custom value for already.
        v = data.get(fieldname, "n/a")
        lineValue += str(v) + ","
    lineValue = Time + "," + lineValue[:-1] + "\n"
    print(lineValue)
    outfile.write(lineValue)
    outfile.close()
```

---

Bonus suggestion: Adding commas between values manually is an error-prone approach. If possible, use `DictWriter`, which takes care of most formatting problems for you.

```
with open(filename,'a') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames)
    row = {}    
    for fieldname in fieldnames: #no need to skip Time here, we'll just overwrite it later.
        row[fieldname] = data.get(fieldname, "n/a")
    row["Time "] = Time
    writer.writerow(row)
```

If you insist on not doing that, at least store the values in a list, which you `join` once at the end:

```
with open(filename,'a') as outfile:
    values = [Time]
    for fieldname in fieldnames[1:]:
        v = data.get(fieldname, "n/a")
        values.append(str(v))
    outfile.write(",".join(values) + "\n")
```

---

Bonus bonus suggestion: if these solutions add extra empty lines between rows that you don't want, you open the file with the `newline=""` argument (if using Python 3):

```
with open(filename,'a', newline="") as outfile:
```

... Or open the file in binary mode (if using Python 2):

```
with open(filename,'ab') as outfile:
```