# Column names are incorrectly named

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas is not labelling columns correctly and it does make sense because I have used this method a few times already. I can not think of anything that goes wrong and I am able to reproduce this error on a new jupyter notebook as well.

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = {'Start Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume',
          'End Time', 'Amount', 'No. Trades', 'Taker Buy Base',
          'Taker Buy Quote', 'N'}
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=columns)
df
```

Sample data

```
test_data = [[1617231600000,
  '538.32000000',
  '545.15000000',
  '535.05000000',
  '541.06000000',
  '8663.58299000',
  1617235199999,
  '4686031.35064850',
  11361,
  '5051.86680000',
  '2733476.69840350',
  '0'],
 [1617235200000,
  '541.11000000',
  '554.67000000',
  '541.00000000',
  '552.49000000',
  '13507.97221000',
  1617238799999,
  '7404389.49931720',
  14801,
  '7736.80002000',
  '4242791.14275430',
  '0'],
 [1617238800000,
  '552.58000000',
  '553.73000000',
  '544.82000000',
  '548.50000000',
  '7115.15238000',
  1617242399999,
  '3907155.60293150',
  5556,
  '3580.46860000',
  '1964701.27448790',
  '0'],
 [1617242400000,
  '548.49000000',
  '550.63000000',
  '544.70000000',
  '545.45000000',
  '3589.18173000',
  1617245999999,
  '1964514.51702120',
  3974,
  '1742.76278000',
  '954042.85262340',
  '0'],
 [1617246000000,
  '545.80000000',
  '545.80000000',
  '540.48000000',
  '541.56000000',
  '4767.67233000',
  1617249599999,
  '2586841.14566500',
  4960,
  '2516.25626000',
  '1364734.14900580',
  '0']]
```

Expected output: The column names should be labelled in the same order as described in the `columns` variable. It is labelled like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFKK8.png) for me, clearly the wrong order. There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653688/preserving-column-order-in-python-pandas-dataframe) but it did not help.

Comment: `df=pd.concat([df[x] for x in columns],1)`?

Comment: You made columns an unordered set. Try making it a list instead.

Comment: "in the same order as described in the columns variable" That value, by design, does not describe an order at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python sets do not maintain order. Use a list (square brackets instead of curly) instead.

```
columns = ['Start Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume',
          'End Time', 'Amount', 'No. Trades', 'Taker Buy Base',
          'Taker Buy Quote', 'N']
```