# understanding csv DictWriter syntax in python

Tags: python, csv

I was looking at the very helpful answer to a previous SO question [which can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086973/how-do-i-convert-this-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-csv-file-python) when attempting to write a list of dicts to a CSV file. The code I used was:

```
with open((filename), 'wb') as outfile:
    write = csv.DictWriter(outfile, keyList)
    write.writer.writerow(keyList)
    write.writerows(data)
```

where keyList is a list of headers for the csv file.

The code worked great, which is nice, but I don't understand why I had to explictly call the underlying `writer` instance to write the keyList (the headers). I tried that line as `write.writerow(keyList)` and it didn't work. I'm curious why that is so I can better understand how Python's DictWriter works.

Is there a cleaner/nicer way of writing this?

Comment: What error does `write.writerow(keyList)` throw?

Comment: @Blender: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: It gives me `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Ah, I forgot `writerow` takes dictionaries, not lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be relying on undocumented behavior. A `DictWriter` object doesn't have an "official" `writer` method.

The [correct way to output the CSV headers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) is to call

```
write.writeheader()
```

Comment: this make sense, but how do I specify the headers for the writeheader function? When I tried to pass keyList in the code `write.writeheader(keyList)` it threw `TypeError: writeheader() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: @kg41: You don't need to - you specified the headers when building the `DictWriter` object. `.writeheader()` is called without parameters (the single argument is the implicit `self`).

Comment: Ignore me, I'm being an idiot. Just called `writeheader()` with no argument and it worked. Thanks @Tim.