# Parsing text file into csv

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a following sample data(it's just a portion)from my text file. I am trying to extract three keys including timestamp,dataFrame, and rssi into csv file.

```
packet"{\"test\":{\"id\":1479238177559,\"deveui\":\"0000000033035032\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-11-15T19:29:37.559Z\",\"dataFrame\":\"ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=\",\"fcnt\":81,\"port\":5,\"rssi\":6,\"snr\":9.5,\"sf_used\":10,\"cr_used\":\"4/5\",\"device_redundancy\":0,\"time_on_air_ms\":288.76800000000003,\"decrypted\":true}}"
Received message in at 2016-11-15 14:29:43.611000
packet"{\"test\":{\"id\":1479238184069,\"deveui\":\"0000000033035032\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-11-15T19:29:44.069Z\",\"dataFrame\":\"ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=\",\"fcnt\":82,\"port\":5,\"rssi\":6,\"snr\":8.5,\"sf_used\":10,\"cr_used\":\"4/5\",\"device_redundancy\":0,\"time_on_air_ms\":288.76800000000003,\"decrypted\":true}}"
Received message in at 2016-11-15 14:29:49.225000
packet"{\"test\":{\"id\":1479238189685,\"deveui\":\"0000000033035032\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-11-15T19:29:49.685Z\",\"dataFrame\":\"ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=\",\"fcnt\":83,\"port\":5,\"rssi\":7,\"snr\":9.5,\"sf_used\":10,\"cr_used\":\"4/5\",\"device_redundancy\":0,\"time_on_air_ms\":288.76800000000003,\"decrypted\":true}}"
Received message in at 2016-11-15 14:29:56.410000
packet"{\"testl\":{\"id\":1479238196868,\"deveui\":\"0000000033035032\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-11-15T19:29:56.868Z\",\"dataFrame\":\"ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=\",\"fcnt\":84,\"port\":5,\"rssi\":3,\"snr\":9.8,\"sf_used\":10,\"cr_used\":\"4/5\",\"device_redundancy\":0,\"time_on_air_ms\":288.76800000000003,\"decrypted\":true}}"
```

Comment: can you update your question with the exact content of your text file? (it seems you are parsing a JSON but the syntax is incorrect) What are you exactly trying to achieve? take same data from a json file and dump it into a csv?

Comment: exact content of my text file is to big. It's literally same data as I showed above. It repeats like packet"{.......}" packet"{...}"

Comment: Deleting your code is not a good way to get people to help, they will want to see that you have tried to solve the problem yourself and aren't asking us to do it for you.

Comment: i am updating in a bit

Comment: Does the file always follow the same pattern in terms of being split up into lines? The way the data is formatted is very odd.

Comment: Each line is 2 JSON objects preceded by the words "packet" and then "Received message ... packet". So you need to split each line in two, then parse the halves as JSON

Comment: After edit .. discard lines starting with "Received", strip the leading 'packet"' and the trailing "'" from the other lines, then parse with json.loads()

Comment: I would suggest you to find an effective way to parse your file. Some suggestion: read the file, split by \n, use a regex to isolate all the string corresponding to a JSON, map the array of strings parsing it as a json, create a new line using the values of the corresponding keys and dump it to a file

Comment: You must convert JSON string to dict, then create list of dicts. Finally, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086973/how-do-i-convert-this-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-csv-file-python

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently data that has accidentally been JSON encoded twice, so it can be decoded twice to get a nice dictionary:

```
import json

with open('log.txt') as infile:
    packet = []
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('packet"{'):
            # Remove 'packet' prefix
            line = line[len('packet'):]
            packet = json.loads(json.loads(line))
            print('Packet:')
            print(packet)
            packet = packet.values()[0]
            print('Values:')
            print(packet['timestamp'], packet['dataFrame'], packet['rssi'])
```

Output:

```
Packet:
{u'test': {u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 81, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-15T19:29:37.559Z', u'dataFrame': u'ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=', u'id': 1479238177559, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': 9.5, u'cr_used': u'4/5', u'deveui': u'0000000033035032', u'device_redundancy': 0, u'rssi': 6, u'port': 5, u'time_on_air_ms': 288.76800000000003}}
Values:
(u'2016-11-15T19:29:37.559Z', u'ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=', 6)
Packet:
{u'test': {u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 82, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-15T19:29:44.069Z', u'dataFrame': u'ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=', u'id': 1479238184069, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': 8.5, u'cr_used': u'4/5', u'deveui': u'0000000033035032', u'device_redundancy': 0, u'rssi': 6, u'port': 5, u'time_on_air_ms': 288.76800000000003}}
Values:
(u'2016-11-15T19:29:44.069Z', u'ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=', 6)
Packet:
{u'test': {u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 83, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-15T19:29:49.685Z', u'dataFrame': u'ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=', u'id': 1479238189685, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': 9.5, u'cr_used': u'4/5', u'deveui': u'0000000033035032', u'device_redundancy': 0, u'rssi': 7, u'port': 5, u'time_on_air_ms': 288.76800000000003}}
Values:
(u'2016-11-15T19:29:49.685Z', u'ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=', 7)
Packet:
{u'testl': {u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 84, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-15T19:29:56.868Z', u'dataFrame': u'ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=', u'id': 1479238196868, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': 9.8, u'cr_used': u'4/5', u'deveui': u'0000000033035032', u'device_redundancy': 0, u'rssi': 3, u'port': 5, u'time_on_air_ms': 288.76800000000003}}
Values:
(u'2016-11-15T19:29:56.868Z', u'ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=', 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
import pandas as pd

content = []
for c in open('log.txt').readlines():
    if c.startswith('packet"{'):
        content.append(c[7:-2].decode('string_escape'))

df = pd.concat([pd.read_json(line, orient='index') for line in content])

df[['dataFrame', 'rssi', 'timestamp']].to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

Data in the out.csv file is:

```
ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=,6,2016-11-15 19:29:37.559
ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=,6,2016-11-15 19:29:44.069
ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=,7,2016-11-15 19:29:49.685
ABzuPdVNxrSEAV8=,3,2016-11-15 19:29:56.868
```