# Python Parse generic Json into table format

Tags: python, json

I am just trying to convert simple Json into CSV making it like a table format, so I can easily load them into my database.

I am trying to create some generic code to parse some Json with different metadata, so I hope I don't have to specify the column name and instead hoping Python will generate the column name itself. 
just like this Json

```
[
 {
  "name":"mike",
  "sal":"1000",
  "dept":"IT",
 },
 {
  "name":"Joe",
  "sal":"1200",
  "dept":"IT",
 }
]
```

to make it format like this:

```
name   sal   dept
Mike   1000  IT
Joe    1200  IT
```

I use the below code but it doesn't work

```
import json
import csv
infile = open(r'c:\test\test.json', 'r')
outfile = open(r'c:\test\test.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
for row in json.loads(infile.read()):
    writer.writerows(row)
```

Can someone show me some sample code to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['name', 'sal', 'dept'])
writer.writeheader()
for i in json.loads(a):
    writer.writerow({'name': i['name'], 'sal': i['sal'], 'dept': i['dept']})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sample code and it seems to be necessary to format your .json with spaces after the colon, like this.

```
[
 {
  "name": "mike",
  "sal": "1000",
  "dept": "IT",
 },
 {
 "name": "Joe",
 "sal": "1200",
 "dept": "IT",
}
]
```

Then you can read in your code line by line into a dict.
Everything else can be found here:

[How do I convert this list of dictionaries to a csv file? [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086973/how-do-i-convert-this-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-csv-file-python)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the `JSON` is fine. You need to make use of `csv.DictWriter` to write to the `csv`. It will also allow you to provide `fieldnames` and hence the `headers` in the `csv` file.

This will do the conversion -

```
import json
import csv
infile = open(r'test.json', 'r')
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'sal', 'dept']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in json.loads(infile.read()):
        print(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Do refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html for further helps.