# reading a JSON file and converting to CSV with python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

i have this json file i wanted to convert it to CSV using pandas

```
  {
        "partes": [
            {
                "processo": "1001824-89.2019.8.26.0493",
                "tipo": "Reqte: ",
                "nome": "Sérgio Izaias Massaranduba  Advogada: Mariana Pretel E Pretel      ",
                "cnpj_cpf": "Não encontrado",
                "oab": "Não encontrado"
            },
            {
                "processo": "1001824-89.2019.8.26.0493",
                "tipo": "Reqda: ",
                "nome": "CLARO S/A   ",
                "cnpj_cpf": "Não encontrado",
                "oab": "Não encontrado"
            }
        ],
        "movimentacoes": [
            {
                "processo": "1001824-89.2019.8.26.0493",
                "data": "28/10/2019",
                "tem_anexo": "",
                "movimentacao": " Distribuído Livremente (por Sorteio) (movimentação exclusiva do distribuidor)  "
            }
        ]
    }
```

when i use the following function `read_json`, 
he returns me one of these error `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

aqui está meu código:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import os

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Suporte\\Desktop\\AUT\\autonomation')


df = pd.read_json('file.json')

df_ = df.to_csv('file.csv', sep=';',index=False)
```

I don't know why he can't read the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON to CSV with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558077/convert-json-to-csv-with-pandas)

Comment: I already tried this POST and it didn't work

Comment: what do you expect the csv to look like?

Comment: separated by commas, in rows and columns

Comment: and what are the columns?

Answer (score 2):

- Remember that `pandas` is about tables of data, with repeating column headers.
- The JSON presented here, as a whole, does not correspond to tabular data.
- This JSON needs to be read in by separate keys
- Alternatively, `partes` and `movimentacoes` must be the same length.

  - Length of `partes` `value` is 2, while `movimentacoes` is 1.
- Given the following data, in a file named `test1.json`

### Data:

```py
{
    "partes": [{
            "processo": "1001824-89.2019.8.26.0493",
            "tipo": "Reqte: ",
            "nome": "Sérgio Izaias Massaranduba  Advogada: Mariana Pretel E Pretel      ",
            "cnpj_cpf": "Não encontrado",
            "oab": "Não encontrado"
        }, {
            "processo": "1001824-89.2019.8.26.0493",
            "tipo": "Reqda: ",
            "nome": "CLARO S/A   ",
            "cnpj_cpf": "Não encontrado",
            "oab": "Não encontrado"
        }
    ],
    "movimentacoes": [{
            "processo": "1001824-89.2019.8.26.0493",
            "data": "28/10/2019",
            "tem_anexo": "",
            "movimentacao": " Distribuído Livremente (por Sorteio) (movimentação exclusiva do distribuidor)  "
        }
    ]
}
```

### Code:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import json

# path to file
p = Path(r'c:\some_path_to_data\test1.json')

# read the JSON file in
with p.open('r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# create the dataframe
df_partes = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['partes'])
print(df_partes)

                  processo     tipo                                                                  nome         cnpj_cpf              oab
 1001824-89.2019.8.26.0493  Reqte:   SÃ©rgio Izaias Massaranduba  Advogada: Mariana Pretel E Pretel        NÃ£o encontrado  NÃ£o encontrado
 1001824-89.2019.8.26.0493  Reqda:                                                           CLARO S/A     NÃ£o encontrado  NÃ£o encontrado

df_movimentacoes = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['movimentacoes'])
print(df_movimentacoes)

                  processo        data tem_anexo                                                                         movimentacao
 1001824-89.2019.8.26.0493  28/10/2019             DistribuÃ­do Livremente (por Sorteio) (movimentaÃ§Ã£o exclusiva do distribuidor)

# save to csv
df_partes.to_csv('partes.csv', index=False)
df_movimentacoes('moviementacoes.csv', index=False)
```

- If the JSON has many keys, consider making a dictionary of dataframes as follows:

```py
df_dict = {key: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data[key]) for key in data.keys()}

# Access a specific dataframe just like a regular dictionary
df_dict['partes']

# save to csv
for key in df_dict.keys():
    df_dict[key].to_csv(f'{key}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I correct, he returns me


ValueError: The DataFrame builder was not called correctly!

Comment: @user158433 I can only help you with the information you've provided.  The code has been tested against the JSON you provided, so I know the syntax is correct.  However, if the entire JSON is significantly different than what's been provided, there may be issues I can't account for.