# I want to search a specific word in my custom google search engine and then filter the output of that search to get the headline

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-custom-search

I can return the output but can not filter the return data using python 3.x

it returns a bunch of result with a unique style and i just only want to get htmlSpinnet and htmlTitle values from the result

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pprint

my_api_key = "xxx"
my_cse_id = "xxx"


def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']


results = google_search(
    'mehkeme', my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=10)

# this is the htmlSpinnets and also htmlTitle
newDict = dict()
# Iterate over all the items in dictionary and filter items which has even keys
for (key, value) in results.items():
    if key == 'htmlSpinnet':
        newDict[key] = value

print('Filtered Dictionary : ')
print(newDict)

# for result in results:
#     pprint.pprint(result)
```

it returns this error

```py
/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrape/venv/bin/python /Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrape/googleCustomSearch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrape/googleCustomSearch.py", line 20, in <module>
    for (key, value) in results.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

it returns this without filtering, and I need to get the values which are bolded

{'cacheId': 'fGQCNF9pc6cJ',
'displayLink': 'azvision.az',
'formattedUrl': 'https://azvision.az/.../mehkeme-huquq-sisteminde-islahatlar-derinlesdirilir-- '
'ferman--.html',
'htmlFormattedUrl': 'https://azvision.az/.../mehkeme-huquq-sisteminde-islahatlar-derinlesdirilir-- '
'ferman--.html',
'**htmlSnippet**': '3 Apr 2019 **...** Prezident İlham Əliyev məhkəmə-hüquq '
'sistemində islahatların dərinləşdirilməsi 
\n'
'haqqında fərman imzalayıb.',
'**htmlTitle**': 'Məhkəmə-hüquq sistemində islahatlar dərinləşdirilir -',
'kind': 'customsearch#result',
'**link**': 'https://azvision.az/news/174505/mehkeme-huquq-sisteminde-islahatlar-derinlesdirilir--ferman--.html',
}

Comment: Where does `Dict` class come from? Did you import it? If you copy this code from somewhere else, can you provide a link?

Comment: i update the code and have a look

Comment: Your `results` variable is a `list` so you can not iterate it like a `dict`. Can you print it out?

Comment: And by the way you should not post your API_KEY and ID to public site like this (if they are legit in this case), someone might take advantage of that.

Comment: thanks for advice and i make it like that, and i share the result withour i am filtering(please look at the question i update it)

Comment: Hmm the stuff you printed out does indeed look like a `dict` but you stil have the `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'` error?

Comment: If you manage to get a `dict` object like the printed stuff then you can extract the information you want by replacing `if key == 'htmlSpinnet':` (line 21) with `if key in '[htmlSpinnet','link','htmlTitle']:`

Comment: same error happening, let's say results=googlesearh is not a dictionary how can i filter then?

Comment: i think it is a list of dictionaries

Comment: If `results` is a list of dictionary then you can use another loop to get the result (or just use `results[0]` if there is only 1 element :D), else I may need you to print `type(results)` to help you resolve this

Comment: it returns that it is a list. Is it means list of dictionaries?

Comment: You can also check by trying `type(results[0])`

Comment: it is a list of dictionaries, so can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you try replacing `for (key, value) in results.items():` with  `for (key, value) in results[0].items():`?

Comment: it works but there is an issue that it only returns one filtered dictionary not the other ones

Comment: Nice, now to get all the stuff create a new list and use a loop to append each newDict to it, like this: https://pastebin.com/0MHYhisz

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrap/googleCustomSearch.py", line 38, in <module>
    for (key, value) in results.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: oh my bad, replace `for (key, value) in results.items()`: with `for (key, value) in result.items():` (remove the `s` in `results`)

Comment: woow it works thanks you, is there any way to instert that data to csv file?

Comment: Yes very simple, you can see some example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086973/how-do-i-convert-this-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-csv-file

Comment: thanks for your great help, I am really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your request to google to ask specifically for 'htmlSnippet' and 'htmlTitle' only by using 'fields' parameter:

```
...&fields=items(htmlTitle,htmlSnippet)...
```

That might make the returned results easier to parse?

See this link for more info: [fields](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/performance.html#partial)

Comment: i will try this out, could you please look at my unasnwered question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218685/using-http-request-get-output-of-each-manually-search-automatically

Comment: I'm not really well versed in python so can't really help you, I just spotted that you only want 2 properties out of the search results so I suggested the solution (which we are using extensively in production and works perfectly).

Comment: thanks anyway, what about searching multiple keywords, like we are creating searhing list and for each of them it returns outputs for each search as a dicttionaries of list. did you get what i mean?

Comment: didn't quite get you there, if you have multiple words then maybe you could run 1 api query per keywords then aggregate the results into a dictionary?