# How to output a dictionary as a csv file : Key and value in same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to put my dictionary of information in a CSV file, but I want it to be this way: each key and its values in the same column.
This method gives each key and its value in the same row, I need to put key and value in the same column
Can anyone help, please?
Thank you

````
for key, val in d.items():
    w.writerow([key, val])
output.close() ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert this list of dictionaries to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086973/how-do-i-convert-this-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: @CodeTalker: no, that puts each datum in a separate column.

Comment: I linked to a duplicate -- in that the *question* shows how to write all the data to one column, while the *problem* is to separate the list.