# How do I print out the values in the "flex" portion of the html in a website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

At the moment I am trying to print out just the information that is held within the flex portion of this table of data, but I am not sure why it is not being read. Everytime I print it out it returns as:

```html
<div id="app">
 <div class="flex loader">
  loading
 </div>
</div>
```

Although I am not sure why it is not reading the data within the "loading" section.

This is my code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium

URL = "https://thestatepress.github.io/SalaryList/dist/index.html?embed=true"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="app")
print(results.prettify())
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read data from a page that dynamically loads content using javascript. The `requests` module just fetches the raw HTML source; it doesn't have a javascript engine. You need to use something like `selenium` to drive a real browser that will correctly handle the dynamic content. You're importing `selenium` in your code, but you're not using it. Take a look at the examples here on Stack Overflow (or elsewhere online) to see how to get started using Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is generated with javascript using [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). You have to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to be able run javascript and get generated page.

In other way it is possible to get data directly without accessing entire page:

```py
import requests
import json

urls = [
  "https://thestatepress.github.io/SalaryList/data-json/ASU-2018.json",
  "https://thestatepress.github.io/SalaryList/data-json/ASU-2021.json"
]

response_data = []

for URL in urls:
  page = requests.get(URL)
  if page.status_code == 200:
    response_data += json.loads(page.text)

# print example piece of data:
print(response_data[10:11])
```

And output will be:

```
[{'jobDescription': 'Program Manager', 'departmentDescription': '...', 'salary': 11111, 'key': '...', 'firstName': '...', 'lastName': '...'}]
```

Or you may use [requests_html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54056631/13946204) ([docs](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/)) python library that support javascript execution (however looks like it is using Selenium-like libraries under the hood so direct usage of Selenium may be more flexible).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to upload the data to an excel file from there? The output seems to be printing as a list, but the list is written as a dictionary inside of a list, so I am not sure how to extract it.

Comment: Yes, it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086973/how-do-i-convert-this-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-csv-file)