# writing a nested dictionary to csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Novice question: I'm trying to write a function to write a nested dictionary to a csv file, so I pulled some code from Stack Overflow ([Convert Nested Dictionary to CSV Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949888/convert-nested-dictionary-to-csv-table)), but I keep getting the error message that "dict" isn't callable. Since I don't really understand what that part of the code is doing it's tough to troubleshoot. 
Can someone please explain and help me fix my code?

Here's my code:

```
def dict_to_csv(dict, txtFileName, destination_file):

    with open(destination_file, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, dict.keys())
        writer.writeheader()
        for key, row in dict.iteritems():
            writer.writerow(dict(row, **{'': key})) #this is the row where I'm getting the error message
    f.closed()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is a sample of the dictionary I'm using: 
{'20140524X21540': {'': '', 'Amateur Built': 'Yes', 'Make': 'KENNETH A BERGER', 'Location': '" Electric City, WA "', 'Total Uninjured': '', 'Latitude': '', 'Event Id': '20140524X21540', 'Airport Name': 'N/A', 'Aircraft Category': 'Unknown', 'Investigation Type': 'Accident', 'Report Status': 'Preliminary', 'Event Date': '05/24/2014', 'Total Fatal Injuries': '1', 'Country': 'United States', 'Weather Condition': 'VMC', 'Registration Number': 'N249PW', 'Accident Number': 'WPR14FA209', 'Number of Engines': '', 'Longitude': '', 'Air Carrier': '', 'Total Serious Injuries': '', 'Airport Code': '', 'Model': 'SEAREY LSX', 'Broad Phase of Flight': '', 'Publication Date': '05/29/2014', 'FAR Description': 'Part 91: General Aviation', 'Engine Type': '', 'Schedule': '', 'Purpose of Flight': 'Personal', 'Aircraft Damage': 'Substantial', 'Injury Severity': 'Fatal(1)', 'Total Minor Injuries': ''}, '20140529X73728': {'': '', 'Amateur Built': '', 'Make': 'ROBINSON HELICOPTER COMPANY', 'Location': '" Chugiak, AK "', 'Total Uninjured': '', 'Latitude': '61.417778', 'Event Id': '20140529X73728', 'Airport Name': '', 'Aircraft Category': 'Helicopter', 'Investigation Type': 'Accident', 'Report Status': 'Preliminary', 'Event Date': '05/28/2014', 'Total Fatal Injuries': '1', 'Country': 'United States', 'Weather Condition': 'VMC', 'Registration Number': 'N392GP', 'Accident Number': 'ANC14FA030', 'Number of Engines': '1', 'Longitude': '-149.500833', 'Air Carrier': '', 'Total Serious Injuries': '', 'Airport Code': '', 'Model': 'R44 II', 'Broad Phase of Flight': '', 'Publication Date': '05/30/2014', 'FAR Description': 'Part 133: Rotorcraft Ext. Load', 'Engine Type': 'Reciprocating', 'Schedule': '', 'Purpose of Flight': 'External Load', 'Aircraft Damage': 'Destroyed', 'Injury Severity': 'Fatal(1)', 'Total Minor Injuries': ''}, '20140320X40839': {'': '', 'Amateur Built': 'No', 'Make': 'CESSNA', 'Location': '" Charlottesville, VA "', 'Total Uninjured': '1', 'Latitude': '38.139722', 'Event Id': '20140320X40839', 'Airport Name': 'CHARLOTTESVILLE-ALBEMARLE', 'Aircraft Category': 'Airplane', 'Investigation Type': 'Accident', 'Report Status': 'Probable Cause', 'Event Date': '03/08/2014', 'Total Fatal Injuries': '', 'Country': 'United States', 'Weather Condition': 'VMC', 'Registration Number': 'N5423J', 'Accident Number': 'ERA14CA160', 'Number of Engines': '1', 'Longitude': '-78.452222', 'Air Carrier': '', 'Total Serious Injuries': '', 'Airport Code': 'CHO', 'Model': '172N', 'Broad Phase of Flight': 'LANDING', 'Publication Date': '05/05/2014', 'FAR Description': 'Part 91: General Aviation', 'Engine Type': 'Reciprocating', 'Schedule': '', 'Purpose of Flight': 'Personal', 'Aircraft Damage': 'Substantial', 'Injury Severity': 'Non-Fatal', 'Total Minor Injuries': ''}}

Comment: Remember, if this answered your question to please accept the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't use object names like `dict` as variables. That error is coming up because you're trying to `call` the variable `dict`.

In the code you mentioned, the purpose of the `dict(...)` line is to convert that `defaultdict` to a regular `dict` to prevent new keys from being created unintentionally. That usage of `dict(...)` is similar to a code snippet like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] # list
b = set(a) # conversion to set
```

The fix is easy: change your variable name!

```
def dict_to_csv(my_dict, txtFileName, destination_file):

    with open(destination_file, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
        writer.writeheader()
        for key, row in my_dict.iteritems():
            writer.writerow(dict(row, **{'': key})) #this is the row where I'm getting the error message
    f.closed()
```

Comment: @sagaderisa that's very strange. Can you post a sample of the dictionary you're using (`my_dict`)?

Comment: @sagaderisa also, make sure you sanitize your code base of errant references to `dict`.

Comment: I just posted the dictionary in the original post - it's too many characters for this.

Comment: @sagaderisa ah. I see. On the `writer.writerow(dict(row, **{'': key}))` line, you want to KEEP `dict` - I'll update my answer for why in a minute. See if it works with that fix!

Comment: That seemed to work - thank you so much! (On to the next error lol)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(dict)
data.to_csv("./filename.csv")
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.