# Trying to parse JSON files with Python to Load into Database

Tags: python, json, pandas

The below is the sample file I have to flatten and convert into a format to be able to load into a database. My approach has been to flatten the dict and convert to CSV and I'm getting a little stuck with the final step of creating a final dataframe with all of the info.

```
    {
    "zipcode":"00544",
    "current":{"canwc":null,"cig":7000,"class":"observation"},
    "triggers":[178,30,176,103,179,112,21,20,48,7,50,40,57]
    }
    {
    "zipcode":"00601",
    "current":{"canwc":null,"cig":null,"class":"observation"},
    "triggers":[12,23,34,28,100]
    }
    {
    "zipcode":"00602",
    "current":{"canwc":null,"cig":null,"class":"observation"},
    "triggers":[13,85,43,101,38,31]
    }
```

The code below thanks to help from @Martijn Pieters will finally get me an iterative printout of all of the dataframes but how do I make it so that I can capture one giant dataframe with all of the pieces essentially concatenated? I could then export that final dataframe to csv etc. (Also is there a better way to upload this result into a database rather than creating a giant dataframe first?)

```
    def lines_per_n(f, n):
        for line in f:
            yield ''.join(chain([line], itertools.islice(f, n - 1)))

    def flatten(jfile):
        for k, v in jfile.items():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                jfile[k] = ','.join(v)
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                for kk, vv in v.items():
                    jfile['%s' % (kk)] = vv
                del jfile[k]
                return jfile

    with open('deadzips.json') as f:
        for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 7):
            try:
                jfile = json.loads(chunk)
                pd.DataFrame(flatten(jfile).items())
            except ValueError, e:
                pass
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Does each json item represent a row in the database?  Depending on the number of items, it might be best to insert rows as you parse the json using sql commands.

Comment: @Jared, each json object in the file would represent 70 rows consisting of the keys and values in each json object so I guess it won't be one row. I was thinking convert to pd.dataframe > csv > load into db with psycopg2 and hoping to automate this because these json files are log files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DictWriter` class of the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) module.

There's an example in this question: [How to write header row with csv.DictWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982023/writing-header-in-csv-python-with-dictwriter)