# Python csv: Optimizing header output

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am writing a huge (160k+) set of data from SQL to a CSV. My script **functions exactly as intended**, but I am sure there has to be a more efficient way of including a header in the output. I cobbled together the following from reading *[writing header in csv python with DictWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982023/writing-header-in-csv-python-with-dictwriter)* but feel like it lacks elegance.

Here's my code:

```
f = open(outfile,'w')
wf = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, restval='OOPS')
wf.writer.writerow(wf.fieldnames)
f.close()

f = open(outfile,'a')
wf = csv.writer(f)
wf.writerows(rows)
f.close()
```

`fieldnames` is defined explicitly (10 custom column names), `rows` contains the `fetchall()` from my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but I don't see why this shouldn't do the job:

```
import csv

with open(outfile, "wb") as outf:
    outcsv = csv.writer(outf)
    outcsv.writerow(fieldnames)
    outcsv.writerows(rows)
```