# How to write Strings to a CSV file in Python by making 2 columns?

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, io

Suppose I have a `loop` which executes like the following:-

```
    for i in range(len(X_test)):
      _, _, ref, hyp = result([X_test[i]],y_test.iloc[i])
      hyp = hyp.replace('<end>', '')
      bleu_score = bleu([ref], hyp, smoothing_function=cc.method3)
      print("Associated BLEU score:",bleu_score,"\n")
      overall_bleu.append(bleu_score)
```

What I would like to do is create a new CSV file, with 2 columns i.e. `Reference (Stands for ref variable in the loop)` and `Predicted (Stands for hyp variable in the loop)` such that for each row, at every successive iteration of the loop, the strings `hyp` and `ref` are written to corresponding columns of a new CSV file (which I would like to create). Any clean way of doing this? I was thinking to use `Pandas`, but seems it will be redundant to write every time within the loop.

Comment: you can use module `csv` to create csv file. You can open file before `for` loop and  write/append single row to file inside `for` loop. If you have simple strings (without comma or enter) then you can even open normal text file and write/append row as text using comma and enter - this way you can also create csv file.

Answer (score -1):

did you try using csv.DictWriter
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

[additionally refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982023/how-to-write-header-row-with-csv-dictwriter)